# Apt-get не работает из за невозможности установки mysql-client.

Tags: linux

```
root@bcontester:/home/user# apt-get -f install
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Исправление зависимостей… Готово
Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
  mysql-client-5.5
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  mysql-client-5.5
обновлено 0, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 910 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 2 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/1 815 kB архивов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 39,1 MB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
ВНИМАНИЕ: Следующие пакеты невозможно аутентифицировать!
  mysql-client-5.5
Установить эти пакеты без проверки? [y/N] y
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 136026 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.42-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.42-1) …
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.42-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 попытка перезаписать «/usr/bin/mysql», который уже имеется в пакете mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: ошибка: подпроцесс вставка уничтожен по сигналу (Обрыв канала)
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.42-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@bcontester:/home/user#
```

Основная проблема: не удается установить mysql-server на ubuntu.

**Обновление**

```
LIST: http://pastebin.ru/4jkmpjdC
librelise: http://pastebin.ru/70EjADIE
ls: http://pastebin.ru/RjoboaKN
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
итого 0
dpkg: http://pastebin.ru/hB3LKkFT
```

Comment: "попытка перезаписать «/usr/bin/mysql», который уже имеется в пакете mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: ошибка: подпроцесс вставка уничтожен по сигналу (Обрыв канала)
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.42-1_amd64.deb"
Вот это настораживает. Какой у Вас дистрибутив?

Comment: Также покажите содержимое /etc/apt/sources.list, вывод команды ls -l /etc/apt/sourceslist.d/, вывод команды dpkg -l | grep mysql.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Денис Шелестов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Виталина, благодарю за форматировние, но был немного искажен смысл. Фраза "покажите содержимое" относиться к файлу /etc/apt/sources.list, а не ко всему абзацу. Поправьте пожалуйста, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 3):

Удалите эту строку из sources.list

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free`

после чего выполните:

`apt-get update`

Что касается mysql-client, он у Вас уже установлен. Можете набрать в консоли mysql и выполнять операции с mysql.
Подключайте "левые" репозитории, только если знаете, что делаете, иначе будут подобные проблемы.